# Using Spring Boot Sockjs in c# client

Tags: java, c#, spring, spring-mvc, stomp

I am trying to connect c# application to spring Boot app using STOMP and websockets I have following test code in NMS and I am getting connection closed Exception when ever I try to connect to web App.

```
 // Example connection strings:
        //    activemq:tcp://activemqhost:61616
        //    stomp:tcp://activemqhost:61613
        //    ems:tcp://tibcohost:7222
        //    msmq://localhost

        Uri connecturi = new Uri("stomp:tcp://localhost:8080/hello");

        Console.WriteLine("About to connect to " + connecturi);

        // NOTE: ensure the nmsprovider-activemq.config file exists in the executable folder.

        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi);

        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
        {
            // Examples for getting a destination:
            //
            // Hard coded destinations:
            //    IDestination destination = session.GetQueue("FOO.BAR");
            //    Debug.Assert(destination is IQueue);
            //    IDestination destination = session.GetTopic("FOO.BAR");
            //    Debug.Assert(destination is ITopic);
            //
            // Embedded destination type in the name:
            //    IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://FOO.BAR");
            //    Debug.Assert(destination is IQueue);
            //    IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "topic://FOO.BAR");
            //    Debug.Assert(destination is ITopic);
            //
            // Defaults to queue if type is not specified:
               IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "Presence");


            Console.WriteLine("Using destination: " + destination);

            // Create a consumer and producer
            using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination))
            using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
            {
```

Or should I use other methods to do that I just need to send some push notifications from Spring Boot web App to c# desktop application.